# Submit tasks with delay based on token

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, callable

guys. I have a task I cannot wrap my head around since I am quite new to multithreading. I want to write a class which will maintaing the following semantics:

```
interface TokenAwareTaskExecutor(){
   //Callable<Long> returns the time the task finishes.
   public void submitTask(String token, Callable<Long> task);
   public long getDelay();
}
```

On submitting the task, the service looks up if such a token has been added by previous invocations. If it is so, the task should be submitted after the delay and after any other submitted task with the same token has been executed. If such a token is not present, add it and submit the task without delay whatsoever. All in all, I want to implement a load balancing strategy which allows to process unique tokens with a given frequency independently. Could you please guide me what to look at?

Answer (score 0):

If there are not too many different tokens, one solution could be to map each token to an instance of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. Then, if the executor was found in the map, schedule the task with the delay. Otherwise, create a new execotur and schedule without delay.

Another approach would be to have only one `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and a map mapping tokens to a `ScheduleInfo` object consisting of an atomic counter that counts how many tasks for that token are waiting and a scheduling time for that last task with that token. Any changes to the counter and the time must occur on tandem and be synchronized.

We wrap each incoming task in an outer Callable that increments the counter upon scheduling using a `synchronized` method `enter()` in `ScheduleInfo`. If the counter was zero, we schedule without delay and set the scheduling time to the current time. If the counter was greater than zero, we add the delay to the scheulding time and schedule for that exact time.

When the inner task is finished, the outer task must decrement the counter again, which happens in another `synchronized` method `exit()` in `ScheduleInfo`. I am not sure how to interpret the delay (time between invocations *or* time between end of one task and start of the next). In the latter case, we have to adjust the schedule time here, too. Again, it is important that `enter` and `exit` can not overlap, therefore must be synchronized.

This is out of my head without trying any code, so I welcome any criticism.

Comment: I dont think ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor can achieve this, there is no fixed delay involved and also this is not a scalable solution.

Comment: OK, so I gave it a bit more thought :)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation will involve following things:

1. Need to store tokens which have been submitted and also status of those token requests: In order to implement this i would create an inner class which contain token name , status of last request, submission time and end time of last request . I will use a ConcurrentHashmap to store corresponding string token as key and instances of each bean as value and  , I will be taking lock on this bean by using synchronize block whenever a request comes in.
2. Everytime a request will come it will check check if token entry exists in map, if not it will create an entry and proceed with task. If entry is present it will try to get lock on bean instance which means that if lock is already taken on bean then it will wait.
3. Once a request has completed its job, it will update its status in corresponding bean before releasing the lock.

Above 2 points basically sets up a freamork for implementation, you can extend this to implement other aspects also like if multiple requests more than 2 comes up then to queue then up sequentially [You can use fairnes lock] , also if you want to ad any additional delay between multiple requests then that can also be done